# Rails: MySQL database table dropped, how to create one

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

Recently I did a mistake (actually foolishness). From phpMyadmin I dropped a table. Now I'm unable to import that table by this command.

```
mysqldump --user <my_name> --password=<my_pass> deve_lockstate thermostat_histories < thermostat_histories.sql
```

I'm also unable to generate migration file cause it's already in ActiveRecord.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: try running `rake db:create` first before running `mysqldump`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> rake db:reset

The rake db:reset task will drop the database, recreate it and load the current schema into it.
You can use this command:

> rake --describe db

to describe the available rake db tasks.